# How to convert from a separate .crt/.p7b file to a .pfx file

Tags: iis, ssl, https, iis-7, ssl-certificate

I have a problem on installation SSL certificate in IIS 7.

I downloaded the ssl certificate from godaddy. I got zip file and I saw two certificate files with .crt and .p7b in zip file.

I tried to install SSL certificate using Complete Certificate Request in IIS. After I installed it, I refreshed the server. When I checked the certificate I installed, it is disappeared in certificate list.

I followed the instructions from godaddy support [link](https://support.godaddy.com/help/article/4801/installing-an-ssl-certificate-in-microsoft-iis-7?countrysite=sg).

I tried many ways to install the certificates but after refreshed, it is gone.

I found a way that it needs to import certificate using import under action in IIS, but it needs .pfx file.

I would like to know how do I change from two certificates (.crt and .p7b) to .pfx file.

Actually, I am not familiar with SSL. So, I appreciate your help. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SSL certificate is not installing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30672552/ssl-certificate-is-not-installing)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may not be able to convert/export .crt/p7b file to pfx as it doesnt contain private key.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new CSR using DigiCert Utility (http://www.digicert.com). Have your CA issue out the domain cert again with the new CSR. 
Then import the crt file in the utility. To enable the option of exporting out a PFX file (which includes both the domain cert and the private key).

Answer (score 1):

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -out example.com.pfx -inkey example.com.key -in example.com.crt -certfile Example-CA-BUNDLE.crt
```

A PEM encoded cert and private key can be combined into PKCS12 easily with OpenSSL on the command line.

Comment: What is `example.com.key`?