# certutil -repairstore opening the smartCard

Tags: iis, certificate

I am trying to install the certificate on an IIS 8.5 server on Windows server 2012.

When going to the IIS manager, I went to 'Server certificates' -> Complete Certificate Request, I select my certificate .p7b and I go to 'Binds' to select the certificate for port 443 of https it is not in the list.

[image]

The problem that is happening is: when I import the certificate, it appears that it was imported. But when you refresh the list of certificates, it does not list any linked / added certificates.

Searching, I found a possible solution:

run -> cmd -> run certutil -repairstore my "paste the serial # in here"

But this command is loading the 'Smart card'.

Comment: https://blog.lextudio.com/the-whole-story-of-server-certificate-disappears-in-iis-7-7-5-8-8-5-10-0-after-installing-it-why-b66e802baa38

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SSL certificate is not installing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30672552/ssl-certificate-is-not-installing)

Comment: The sollution anwser not resolved.  So I've rephased the question with a different error return.

Comment: On which machine did you create the certificate request? Complete the request there and then export a PFX for other machines.

Comment: On the server machine. When generating try to generate the PFV, returns: (unable to load certificates)

Comment: @ViníciusMatos Did you find a workaround for this?

Comment: @RahulSharma I decided to import the certificate through IIS

Comment: @ViníciusMatos How did you do that? I do not have my password when I a try to import the certificate.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/ojdif1

Comment: @ViníciusMatos Yes I did try the `import` button, but it asks for a password which I do not have. How did you generate the .pfx file?

Comment: @RahulSharma The file I had from another server. Then I created a new server, took the digital certificate file and imported it.